# Update NVRAM so that shimx64.efi is run instead of grubx64.efi on Debian system for secure boot

Tags: debian, uefi, firmware, secure-boot

I want to configure my Debian to boot with secure boot enabled but it doesn't and here is why...

---

OS specific boot loaders are stored on the `ESP` partition which is mounted in `/boot/efi`

Debian system has it's own sub directory there called `debian` and here are the contents of this folder:

```bash
sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI/debian
```

Output of the command is:

```
BOOTX64.CSV  fbx64.efi  grub.cfg  grubx64.efi  mmx64.efi  shimx64.efi
```

According to my understanding, to make Debian boot with secure boot enabled the EFI should execute `shimx64.efi` which will in turn execute `grubx64.efi` (which is currently executing boot loader)

Is that correct? please correct me if not.

I did investigate why my Debian doesn't work with secure boot by issuing the following command:

```bash
efibootmgr -v
```

Here is output of the above command (please scroll to the right)

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001
Boot0001* debian        HD(1,GPT,4cc75323-a915-4249-9c01-e553cf705ad4,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\debian\grubx64.efi)..BO
```

This output represent boot entries (stored in `NVRAM`), currently there is only one which executes `GRUB` boot manager called `grubx64.efi`.

According to this, it's obvious that EFI executes `grubx64.efi` directly rather than executing `shimx64.efi` and that must be the reason why secure boot doesn't work with my Debian system.

My question is, how do I edit this boot entry so that is executes `shimx64.efi` instead and whether this will make Debian work with secure boot enabled without making the system un-bootable?

Can you in addition please tell why wasn't `shimx64.efi` set to `NVRAM` instead of `grubx64.efi` to make secure boot work out of the box.

It's strange because many people report that secure boot works out of the box.

---

For additional information, I'm using Debian 12, freshly installed without any custom or proprietary drivers that would interfere with secure boot.

**EDIT:**

I have issued the following command to add new entry:

```bash
sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sdb -p 1 -L DebianShim -l \\EFI\\debian\\shimx64.efi
```

This now results in two entries:

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

Output:

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001
Boot0000* DebianShim    HD(1,GPT,4cc75323-a915-4249-9c01-e553cf705ad4,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* debian        HD(1,GPT,4cc75323-a915-4249-9c01-e553cf705ad4,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\debian\grubx64.efi)..BO
```

I have of course made sure to make my new entry active by changing the order:

```bash
sudo efibootmgr -b 0001 -o 0000
```

Problem regardless is that upon reboot my new entry is not preserved, it's gone.
Here is relevant question with same issue:
https://superuser.com/questions/1166398/efi-settings-set-via-efibootmgr-are-ignored-after-reboot

I have also tried to delete original boot entry and add new one but it reverts back to old entry, the one that executes `grubx64.efi`

Further google research reveals that this might be a bug with `MSI` motherboards, that is their firmware.

However it's worth noting that setting some other options such as timeout works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

If I'm reading this right, it sounds as if the EFI Boot Manager does not update the variables in the NVRAM.  I say this because I have the same issue, and "working around it" takes a bit, which I will attempt to explain.  The issue is that if the UEFI firmware isn't accessed directly, the EFI variables are loaded in with read-only privileges

### Solution

As you stated, I'm assuming you have an MSI branded motherboard with a version of LiveUpdate firmware installed on it (that is the same motherboard brand that I have that also has buggy UEFI firmware).  If not, know that this procedure will work regardless of the manufacturer because it accesses the NVRAM through the UEFI Shell. without use of the OS.

Steps:

1. Format a USB stick (at least 8GB in size) FAT32
2. Download the ISO Image/CD-R Image from Roderick Smith's Great EFI Bootloader: [Getting rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html).  I've linked to the download page in case youu want to research the bootloader (The reason this was done was to prevent the Chicken or the Egg Problem - You must have at least a shell to access the shell.  This disk image already contains an EFI shell that is pristine).

   - If you'd rather just have a bootable shell, you can download a newer pre-compiled binary from this Github Repository: [UEFI-Shell](https://github.com/pbatard/UEFI-Shell)
3. Use Rufus or another image creation tool like `dd` to write the CD-R image to USB.

   - If you downloaded just the shell, follow [HowTo-create-a-UEFI-Shell-Boot-Device](https://github.com/KilianKegel/Howto-create-a-UEFI-Shell-Boot-Drive), skipping step 3 because you've already downloaded a binary in this step 2 above.
4. Reboot your PC with the newly created USB device.

   - If you chose the CD-R method, use your arrow keys and press the right arrow until UEFI shell is highlighted and press `Enter`
   - If you chose just the Shell method, the system should boot right up and drop directly to the shell.

### Next Steps

You should now be in the UEFI shell, and will be able to modify the variables and values directly.  Do the following:

1. See what's already there:`bcfg boot dump`
2. Determine the location of the EFI partition that requires updating: `dir fsX:` where X is a disk number starting at 0 and ending at your disk count minus 1.  We are looking for the disk that the `EFI` directory resides on, i.e., `fs0:\EFI`
3. Keep listing directories nested in EFI until you fid the location of the Shim.efi file you want to add.  I believe in your case, this would be: `fsX:\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi`
4. Take the result from step 3, and issue the following command: `cfg boot add 0 <location from step 3> DebianShim`

DebianShim can actually be anything as this is the text the bootloader uses to display the entry.  0 can be any number between 0 and 9 I believe.  This is the boot order, so 0 would be at the top.

*Side Note*: I believe for this change to be completed you must boot into the LiveUpdate Setup Utility and turn off CSM, only if your Windows version was installed in UEFI mode.

---

### Sources

[Restoring EFI NVRAM boot entries with rEFInd and Rufus](https://pete.akeo.ie/2014/05/restoring-efi-nvram-boot-entries-with.html) - This is the link I used to solve this problem my first time.  Ignore the comment RE: Disaster as `efibootmanager` is what you were using.